# Update Panel Missing Data

Tags: updatepanel

I have a update panel with a gridview inside. The gridview works fine when it loads from the start (if i look at the "view source" all data is there), but when a postback is done on that updatepanel and click "view source" again the other data i fetched was not there. It still has the old data.

But if i refreshes the whole page, i'm getting it all. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code to show us what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, please show us the source code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View Source in browsers does not generally display any dynamic changes made to the HTML (i.e. changes resulting from an asynchronous post-back on an UpdatePanel). It will just give you the HTML that was received from the initial page request. If you're using Firefox, using Firebug to inspect the markup should show you dynamic changes. If you've got IE8 the Developer Tools will do the same thing. If you've got IE6 or 7 (or 8), the [FullSource](http://www.thundermain.com/FullSource.html) extension will display the HTML for what's currently displayed, not the initial page response.